# SQL pivot table error

Tags: sql, asp.net, pivot-table

Hi guys when i call a stored procedure on asp.net i am getting this error -

> Procedure or function 'uspTargetQuantites' expects parameter
>   '@Product', which was not supplied.

my stored procedure ...

```
USE [WorkstationCells]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[uspTargetQuantites]    Script Date: 11/04/2018 08:27:38 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspTargetQuantites] (@Product VARCHAR(10))
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

/* debug */
--DECLARE @Product VARCHAR(10)
--SET @Product = 'G120C'
/* debug */


SELECT Product 
              , Framesize 
              , HourName 
              , Quantity 
INTO #PivotData
FROM WorkstationCells.dbo.TargetQuantites
WHERE Product = @Product


SELECT DISTINCT Framesize INTO #PivotDataProducts FROM #PivotData


DECLARE @PivotColumnHeaders VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @PivotColumnHeaders = 
  COALESCE(
    @PivotColumnHeaders + ',[' + cast(Framesize as varchar) + ']',
    '[' + cast(Framesize as varchar)+ ']'
  )
FROM #PivotDataProducts    

DECLARE @PivotTableSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @PivotTableSQL = N'
SELECT * FROM #PivotData AS PivotData
      PIVOT (SUM(Quantity)FOR Framesize IN (' + @PivotColumnHeaders + ')) AS PivotTable
'

EXECUTE(@PivotTableSQL)

DROP TABLE #PivotData
DROP TABLE #PivotDataProducts


--EXEC uspTargetQuantites 'G120C'
```

Can anybody tell me whats going wrong...?

Here is my c# code... to call the SP

```
    public void Refreshdata()
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Server=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Database=WorkstationCells");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[uspTargetQuantites]", con);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: where is the call to the sp? the message is clear. you arent passing the parameter

Comment: public void Refreshdata()
        {
           
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Server=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Database=WorkstationCells");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[uspTargetQuantites]", con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sda.Fill(ds);
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}

Comment: Please add the code to the question and format properly

Comment: added the code, thanks in advance

Comment: You need add the parameter to the command. Let me know if the duplicated answer solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry for the newbie questions as i am new but what extra do i need to add into my code to get it to pass in the param.

Comment: check the duplicated question the part `Parameters.Add()`